# Php remove element from associative array with it's position

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array like this:

```
$arr = array('id' => 3, 'title' => 'lorem ipsum');
```

Now, I want to remove first element from array regardless of it's key, because 'id' can sometimes be 'm_id', 'e_id'...

That is why I can't use unset['id'], but I can't use unset[0] either, because 0 is not it's key.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: @GergoErdosi It will not work if `id` key is on the second position.

Comment: @hsz, doesn't matter. OP asked for the first element.

Comment: Doesn't metter, id will always be on the first position, it will only change name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_shift($arr);`

For the array `$arr = array('id' => 3, 'title' => 'lorem ipsum');`, this will return `3` and change the array `$arr` to `$arr = array('title' => 'lorem ipsum');`.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out, array_shift() shift is the best function to remove the first element from any array. To remove a "numbered" element from an associative array (e.g. the 2nd element:

```
$arr = array('id' => 3, 'category' => 'test data', 'title' => 'lorem ipsum');
$element = 2;

$element = array_keys($arr)[$element-1];
unset($arr[$element]);
```

This will remove the `category` element from the array

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

```
$arr = array('id' => 3, 'title' => 'lorem ipsum');
$arr = array_slice($arr, 1);
```